# Split String Before array of string in Python

Tags: python, string, split

Hello I have another problem with split string

First it was when spliting by second upper letter like this (thanks for Omire):

```
def split_second_upper(string):
    second_upper = False
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i].isupper() and i != 0:
            second_upper = True
        if second_upper:
            return string[0:i], string[i:]
```

It was good before I get another list of product when harder to split

some exaple product:

```
Veltebøyle Toyota Hi Lux Double Cab 2019 -
Frontbøyle EC Godkjent Super Bar Inox AUDI Q5 2008-2015
Frontbøyle Høy Medium Bar Mark Inox CHEVROLET Captiva 2011 >
Stigtrinn Grand Pedana Inox VOLKSWAGEN Amarok Trend Line 2010 >
Stigtrinn Grand Pedana Inox CITROËN C-Crosser 2008 >
Frontbøyle Polert Standard Toyota Hilux 10-15
```

First product its ok but other have more upper letters

the best way Its lower all letters before model list I can create array with model car (maybe without first)

like

```
Stigtrinn Grand Pedana Inox VOLKSWAGEN Amarok Trend Line 2010 >
```

to:

```
Stigtrinn grand pedana inox VOLKSWAGEN Amarok Trend Line 2010 >

car=['Audi','Bmw','Chevrolet','Citroen','Dacia','Daihatsu','Dodge','Fiat','Ford','Honda','Hyundai','Isuzu','Iveco','Jeep','Kia','Land Rover','Mazda','Mercedes','Mitsubishi','Nissan','Opel','Peugeot','Porsche','Renault','Seat','Skoda','SsangYong','Subaru','Suzuki','Toyota','Volkswagen','Volvo',]
```

Or maybe its possible to split in loop  before car(from array) ?

split like:

```
 Stigtrinn Grand Pedana Inox 
 VOLKSWAGEN Amarok Trend Line 2010 >
```

UPADETE:

I CREATE Function like this:

```
def split_car(string):
   car_array=['Audi','Bmw','Chevrolet','Citroen','Dacia','Daihatsu','Dodge','Fiat','Ford','Honda','Hyundai','Isuzu','Iveco','Jeep','Kia','Land Rover','Mazda','Mercedes','Mitsubishi','Nissan','Opel','Peugeot','Porsche','Renault','Seat','Skoda','SsangYong','Subaru','Suzuki','Toyota','Volkswagen','Volvo',]
   for car in car_array:
       if car in string:
           a, b = string.split(" " + car + "", 1)
           b = car + b
           return (a, b)
```

but now i need to ignore upper and lower letter from string car  couse some times Bmw can be BMW or bmw  how i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a diverse (a.k.a. "messy") input, better not rely on the other side having used capitals and lowercase in a consistent way. Here is an implementation of looking up every word in an approved list (a "whitelist") of car brands while ignoring any case differences.

```
text = [ 'Veltebøyle Toyota Hi Lux Double Cab 2019 -',
    'Frontbøyle EC Godkjent Super Bar Inox AUDI Q5 2008-2015',
    'Frontbøyle Høy Medium Bar Mark Inox CHEVROLET Captiva 2011 >',
    'Stigtrinn Grand Pedana Inox VOLKSWAGEN Amarok Trend Line 2010 >',
    'Stigtrinn Grand Pedana Inox CITROËN C-Crosser 2008 >',
    'Frontbøyle Polert Standard Toyota Hilux 10-15' ]

brands = ['Audi','Bmw','Chevrolet','Citroen','Citroën','Dacia','Daihatsu','Dodge','Fiat',
    'Ford','Honda','Hyundai','Isuzu','Iveco','Jeep','Kia','Land Rover','Mazda','Mercedes',
    'Mitsubishi','Nissan','Opel','Peugeot','Porsche','Renault','Seat','Skoda','SsangYong',
    'Subaru','Suzuki','Toyota','Volkswagen','Volvo']

def split_by_brand (string):
    string = string.split()
    brands_cased = [brand.upper() for brand in brands]
    for index,word in enumerate(string):
        if word.upper() in brands_cased:
            return ' '.join(string[:index]),' '.join(string[index:])

for line in text:
    model,brand = split_by_brand (line)
    print ('model "{}", brand "{}"'.format(model,brand))
```

Result:

```
model "Veltebøyle", brand "Toyota Hi Lux Double Cab 2019 -"
model "Frontbøyle EC Godkjent Super Bar Inox", brand "AUDI Q5 2008-2015"
model "Frontbøyle Høy Medium Bar Mark Inox", brand "CHEVROLET Captiva 2011 >"
model "Stigtrinn Grand Pedana Inox", brand "VOLKSWAGEN Amarok Trend Line 2010 >"
model "Stigtrinn Grand Pedana Inox", brand "CITROËN C-Crosser 2008 >"
model "Frontbøyle Polert Standard", brand "Toyota Hilux 10-15"
```

This is *not* fault tolerant (nor is it "easy" to make it so). If, for example, a brand is missing from the list or simply mis-spelled in the original text, then you will get an error.
For example, I had to add the correctly spelled `'Citroën'` to your original list of brands so it matched the text.

Comment: Yea u do this better then me. I just have hard problem with upper and lower letters.

Only i dont know what i doing wrong i try to upper all but not works correct like in your Script

Thx For help!